# Как делается такое с записью в базе mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Хочу реализовать что то такое:
Имеем на сайте кнопку и имеем счётчик:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как я нажал на **"Добавить в любимые"**, становится так +1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После того как нажал **"Удалить из любимых"** -1 стало.

В JS я понял как это всё реализовать. Добавляет и удаляет "+1", "-1". Но я не могу понять как сделать, чтоб оно записалось и пользователи видели "кто сколько нажал" в общем кликов. Для каждого товара, свой счётчик получается.

Таблица: **ok_products**

Столбец сделал: **loves**

Структура: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите идеи, может кто такое реализовывал???

размета html где счётчик

```
<span class="loves" id="loves_{$product->id}">
   <span name="loves">{$product->loves}</span> 
   Влюблёны
</span>
```

Разметка кнопки нажатия

```
<div class="whilist">
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="fn_wishlist wishlist_button-right serdce"></span>
                                        {if $smarty.get.module != "WishlistView"}
                                            {if $product->id|in_array:$wished_products}
                                                <a href="#" data-id="{$product->id}" class="fn_wishlist wishlist_button selected like" title="{$lang->remove_favorite}" data-result-text="{$lang->add_favorite}">
                                                    <span class="buttom-delete">Удалить из любимыx</span>
                                                </a>
                                            {else}
                                                <a href="#" data-id="{$product->id}" class="fn_wishlist wishlist_button" title="{$lang->add_favorite}" data-result-text="{$lang->remove_favorite}">
                                                    <span class="buttom-add">{$lang->dobavit_v_lyubimye_}</span>
                                                </a>
                                            {/if}
                                        {/if}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Сам Jquery который делает накидал временно так:
**Добавление +1**

```
$(document).on('click', '.wishlist_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lovesAmmount = $("[name='loves']");

    $('.loves span').html(lovesAmmount.val() + 1);
});
```

**Удаление -1**

```
$(document).on('click', '.wishlist_button.selected', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lovesAmmount = $("[name='loves']");

    $('.loves span').html(1 - 1);
});
```

Сайт сам [ссылка](http://beautyhub.pro/products/botoks-melado-de-cana)

Ajax сделал:

```
$(".wishlist_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/loves.php',         /* Куда пойдет запрос */
        method: 'post',             /* Метод передачи (post или get) */
        dataType: 'html',          /* Тип данных в ответе (xml, json, script, html). */
        data: {name: $("#name").val()},     /* Параметры передаваемые в запросе. */
        success: function(data){   /* функция которая будет выполнена после успешного запроса.  */
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Сайт loves.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
        //$product_id = intval(str_replace('product_', '', $_POST['id']));
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        //$name = "321";
        $query = $okay->db->placehold("UPDATE ok_products SET loves = '.$name.' WHERE id = '214'");

        $okay->db->query($query);
        //$product = $okay->db->result();

    }
```

Разметка html:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

В итоге имеем кнопку и имеем input, где ввожу любое число и где сердце закрашенное выводит, только в запросе 1 товар

Comment: Уточните Ваш вопрос. Пока не совсем понятно что требуется. Вам необходимо 1. Подключиться к БД. 2. При нажатии кнопки записывать данные в базу. В Вашем случае через php, как понимаю. 3. На странице, где находится данное поле - делаете запрос в БД  по идентификатору продукта и выводите в форму через js или php.

Comment: Человек зашёл, нажал кнопку, добавилось +1, записалась в базу запись, и появилась в  шаблоне. Если человеку не надо это больше - нажал опять кнопку эту же, цифра уменьшилась на 1, в базе уменьшилось у товара число и вывело в шаблон.

Comment: а в чём проблема то? Вы умеете подключаться через код к БД?

Comment: Подключать умею, в интернете полно. Не могу вкурить ajax + php запрос.

Comment: Выкладывайте Ваш код и разметку html, иначе это надолго. Задача простейшая.

Comment: Вверху написал, что то если надо скажите дополню

Comment: "В JS я понял как это всё реализовать." - Нет, еще не поняли. Что есть `'.wishlist_button'`, и где оно находится?

Comment: Он обрабатывает 2 функцию, записывает в кукис пользователю http://beautyhub.pro/wishlist

Comment: Я не понимаю что это значит и не хочу ходить по ссылкам. Всю информацию - в вопрос.

Comment: При нажатие этой кнопки, происходит у пользователя запись в браузере. Где выводит список его Любимых товаров. К этой кнопке хочу так же привязать, чтоб при нажатие пользователь не только свой список пополнял, но ещё и записывалось в базу к товару количество, сколько пользователей нажали.

Comment: Всю информацию - в вопрос. Я Вам сейчас минус поставлю.

Comment: Я добавил саму кнопку в вопрос, что вы спрашивали, я новенький тут.

Comment: Этих штук `'.wishlist_button'` много на странице?

Comment: 1 элемент на странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил переменную

`$id = $_POST['id'];`

Добавил запрос

`$query = $okay->db->placehold("UPDATE ok_products SET loves = '$plus_love' WHERE id = '$id'");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $okay->db->placehold("UPDATE ok_products SET loves = '.$name.' WHERE id = '214'");
```

У вас тут в запросе ошибка, а именно там где точки возле переменной .$name., я так понимаю, вы хотели сделать конкатенацию строк? Правильный вариант:

```
$query = $okay->db->placehold("UPDATE ok_products SET loves = '" . $name . "' WHERE id = '214'");
```

Возможно после этих изменений все заработает. Ведь этим запросом, вы пытались сделать вставку строки `.$name.` в поле, у которого тип int, и база данных скорее всего выдавала вам ошибку.

Так же, рекомендую обратить внимание на название переменных - они явно не совсем хорошо названы, например переменная `$name` казалось бы, что там должно быть какое-то имя/название а там я так понимаю значение количества лайков.